# Position Bootstrap typeahead menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I have a modal window, which is opened from the main window.

Now this modal dialog has a textbox (kind of auto-suggest) and the user gets list of suggestions as he types. I am using the Bootstrap typeahead for the same.

So I use

```
typeTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
    var _input = me.$element,
        _offset = _input.offset();

    _menu.css({
        position: "fixed",
        height: "auto",
        overflow: "visible",
        left: _offset.left,
        top: _offset.top + _input.outerHeight(),
        "z-index": 999999
    });
}, 5);
```

Now my question is if the modal is called without scrolling on the main window, the list of suggestions appear in the correct position (i.e. just below the textbox)

However, lets say I scroll vertically down and then call the modal dialog, in that case, my suggestions does not appear in the correct position vertically (they move down).

How do I fix this issue?

I have tried changing position from fixed to absolute, but this does not help, since my parent for the suggestions is relative div.

Comment: Use position absolute and adjust top and left.

Comment: like i said...i did try that already...but it does not help

Comment: Because you didn't do it right. This is how it should be done: position absolute relatively to parent container with adjusted top and left. The best you can do is to set up a demo, otherwise it's hard to help.